# CodeLens in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Is there a way to enable CodeLens in Visual Studio for Mac ?

I have the latest version of VS for Mac as today 8.10.6 (build 10)

Comment: I would start by looking at this extension and see what they do https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=artbrain.codelens-sample

Comment: Thanks @Sam but I would like to have the one made by Microsoft in the Windows version

Comment: I think [Gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) might use codelens

Answer (score 0):

It's look like is on the RoadMap already for v8.11 but it's not clear when they are going to launch that version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/mac-roadmap