# How can i get codelens on visual studio for macOS?

Tags: visual-studio

On MacOS nothing options in tools visual studio

anyone can help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). StackOverflow is for specific programming problems. From [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/12/code-lens-roundup): `"typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true`.

Comment: That documentation is for Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio.

Comment: As of Summer 2021, CodeLens had not been implemented for Visual Studio for macOS yet: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68458314/2988. Not sure what the current status is.